# RuntimeMBeanCallable.call() exception

Tags: websphere, ibm-mobilefirst

When a .wlapp file is deployed in MobileFirst Console, we get the following error in the logs. This happened after we upgraded MobileFirst Server from 6.3 to 7, but don't know if this is related to the version of MobileFirst.

```
000001c6 BaseTransacti E   RuntimeMBeanCallable.call() exception
                                                                                              java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException

    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy166.deployApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.ApplicationDeploymentTransaction.prepareMBean(ApplicationDeploymentTransaction.java:919)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.util.RuntimeMBeanWorkerThreadCaller$RuntimeMBeanCallable.call(RuntimeMBeanWorkerThreadCaller.java:76)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.util.RuntimeMBeanWorkerThreadCaller.callSynchronously(RuntimeMBeanWorkerThreadCaller.java:183)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.util.RuntimeMBeanPoolCaller.callRuntimeMBeans(RuntimeMBeanPoolCaller.java:91)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.BaseTransaction.prepare(BaseTransaction.java:450)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.BaseTransaction.internalRun(BaseTransaction.java:348)
    at com.ibm.worklight.admin.actions.BaseTransaction$1.run(BaseTransaction.java:235)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:790)
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorException: ADMC0009E: The system failed to make the SOAP RPC call: invoke
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.invokeTemplateOnce(SOAPConnectorClient.java:894)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.invokeTemplate(SOAPConnectorClient.java:689)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.invokeTemplate(SOAPConnectorClient.java:679)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.invoke(SOAPConnectorClient.java:665)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.invoke(SOAPConnectorClient.java:487)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy121.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminClientImpl.invoke(AdminClientImpl.java:224)
    at com.worklight.common.util.jmx.WASRuntimeMBeanHandler$AdminClientMBeanServerConnection.invoke(WASRuntimeMBeanHandler.java:521)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanProxy$InvokeHandler.invoke(MXBeanProxy.java:146)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanProxy.invoke(MXBeanProxy.java:160)
    at javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.invoke(MBeanServerInvocationHandler.java:246)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: [SOAPException: faultCode=SOAP-ENV:Client; msg=Read timed out; targetException=java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out]
    at org.apache.soap.transport.http.SOAPHTTPConnection.send(SOAPHTTPConnection.java:479)
    at org.apache.soap.rpc.Call.WASinvoke(Call.java:510)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient$8.run(SOAPConnectorClient.java:852)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.invokeTemplateOnce(SOAPConnectorClient.java:845)
    ... 21 more
```

MobileFirst version 7
WAS server version 8.5.5.5
JRE version 1.6

Comment: Make sure the server and/or port values did not change.

Comment: Waiting to hear back from you.

Comment: Hi Idan, thank you very much for replying. there was some installation problem, so re - installed the server. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Re-deploying the MobileFirst artifacts to the application server should normally not be required as inspecting the logs and configuration usually will lead to the root cause of the problem. However in some cases starting over to get things right will work.

As mentioned in the comments, re-deployment of the server artifacts nullified the issue that was experienced.